# Zend Http conf setting to Windows 7

Tags: apache, zend-framework, virtualhost

I'm following Zend beginner tutorial. In that actually following need to be setup in the local server Apache httpd.conf in Linux PC.

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/square/public"
    ServerName square.localhost
    </VirtualHost>
```

But I've a Windows 7 installed with Xampp in my local. Could anyone please help me on this how to put this in my local httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/square/public"` to a public folder of your project. For example, to `"C:\XAMPP\www\square\public"` or wherever your project's public folder is located.

Also make sure you have this line in your hosts file : `127.0.0.1 localhost`

Comment: I've tried above your instruction and it's working fine. Now when I tried to go to the http://localhost/ it's now redirecting to the http://square.localhost/ any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add 127.0.0.1 square.localhost to C:/Windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts

Comment: I've added it but still it's same. There's small correction on my last comment it's not actually redirecting it's displaying square.localhost zend home page when I go to the localhost url.